# Performance of two arrays comparison in ruby

Tags: ruby, comparison, detection

I have 2 arrays :

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
arr2 = [1,2, 82, 167,3,79,4]
```

I would use `Array#-` to get the difference as following:

```
arr1 - arr2
#=> [82,167,79]
```

Let's say now I have a ten thousand elements arrays.  How do I measure a `Array#-` performance? Is there another method to compare with ?

Comment: They are right though. This is not for letting others do your work but for asking and answering knowledge questions.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449147/most-efficient-way-to-compare-arrays-in-ruby) question?

Comment: I'm not asking people to do my work here. I'm seeking exactly knowledge, established technics from the community and any drawbacks encountered by experienced people. And that would help me in my work..

Comment: One way to ask is: _"Does Array#- have good performance?"_. Another way to ask is: _"How do I measure a method's performance?"_.

Comment: @Stefan Fair enough. I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You should use ruby Benchmark built in stdlib:

```
require 'benchmark'

a = [*1..10000]
b = [*35..11000]

puts Benchmark.measure{ a - b }

# output on my system shown 
#0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002996)

Benchmark.measure{ a - b }
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fe2fa8bad28 @label="", @real=0.003237861965317279, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.0, @total=0.0>
```

For more info see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Comment: Backticks and semicolons?

Comment: @Stefan backtics were typo, fixed. semi-colons were because I ran in pry session and didn't want to see object returned since it was just big array of numbers. I removed them but they don't break anything.

Comment: @lacostenycoder I found your answer helpful and voted up as I learned about Benchmark class. I don't know why people overreact and down vote that fast..